# Can we backport Magento 2.3.x code to Magento 2.2.x and 2.1.x

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, comparison

I have an extension that works on 2.2.x and 2.1.x and 2.3.x. 
Magento recently has added MSI support in 2.3.x. I wanted to support this new feature in the extension. But some 2.3.x relate classes are not present "Source" related classes.
Is there a way I can still use the extension with MSI related changes in magento <2.3.x.
e.g. this class

`Class Magento\\InventoryApi\\Api\\Data\\SourceItemInterface`

Currently we may have to release two extension for different magento versions which is not ideal.